# Is there a Windows kernel API to get current CPU usage percent, or idle percent?

Tags: windows, driver, wdm

I ask this question because I'd like to know this from my *kernel mode* Windows driver.

I have some library code porting from user mode that has some accompanying stress test to run; that stress test code need to know when CPU is idle.

Simple googling shows no result, at least from first several pages.

Answer (score 1):

you need use [ZwQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with `SystemProcessorPerformanceInformation` infoclass ( you got a array of SYSTEM_PROCESSOR_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION structures on output)